# Redirect page after showing an alert message in C#

Tags: c#

I want to refresh the page after showing an alert to the user in C#

I tried

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertscript", "alert('Data has been saved and submitted');", true); 
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
```

The page gets redirected but I am not getting alert

I also tried

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertscript", "var r = confirm('Data has been saved and submitted confirm'); if (r == true) { <%#namespace.project.class().PageRefresh()%> } else { <%#new namespace.project.class().PageRefresh()%> } ", true);

public void PageRefresh() {

            Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
        }
```

In this case I am getting alert but the reload is not happening

I don't want to use client side page refresh like the ones below

```
location.reload(true)
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

I want to use

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
```

but it should execute after alerting the user

Comment: Not possible.  If you ponder the 2 lines of C# you propose you should pretty quickly see why it will not work.

Comment: If looking at the code is not enough, then load up Fiddler and take a look at what those lines actually do.

Answer (score 2):

Why first attempt do not work: during the request, you are registering a new script and then tells IIS to perform redirect, page with script is not returning to user and simply redirects, as it is required on the IIS level, instead of browser.

Why second attempt do not work: you are trying to inject c# code into the client script **after** the page was compiled. So `<%#...%>` will not be compiled and it will look as is in the resulting markup, you can look into result code with browser element inspector, which will prove it.

Although you do not want to do it, but it should be implemented on the client side, as page will not call c# back-end code after it was rendered and before page was posted. Actually, you can achieve it in different ways:

First way is to register required `alert` script with immediate reload after it. As `alert` breaks page execution, user will not be redirected until he do not press OK in the alert window. This way is simple and understandable.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertscript", "alert('Data has been saved and submitted'); location.reload(true);", true);
```

Another way is to perform form `submit` after `alert` and implement redirect on the server-side, as you do not want to write some js.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertscript", "alert('Data has been saved and submitted'); document.forms[0].submit();", true);
```

and in the `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
    }
}
```